# Django web server starts but does not request anything

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, server, webserver

[solved] Please check my comment
So here is how problem started. I had Python 3.6.4 installed on my windows machine like for 4 month. Everthing was normal. Yesterday I decided to update to Python 3.7.0. I asked around and knew that there is no way but uninstalling old version and installing again. So I did it. But since I have done that, I run my django server, it starts, tells me it runs on 127.0.0.1:8000 but it does not request anything, I mean website is not loading. I look at terminal, no requests or anything. I wondered if there is problem with project, and copied it run it on manjaro on virtualbox. It worked perfectly.
How do I solve this problem? It does not gives me any error. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you use environment wrapper or have installed python and django directly to your pc?

Comment: No I dont use any enviroment

Comment: Did your internal firewall block port 8000?

Comment: how can I check it if it's blocked?

Answer (score 1):

So here is how I solved it. I have ubuntu(subsystem) installed in my windwos 10 machine and I have virtualbox. It worked on virtualbox but not in windows 10 or on ubuntu. I remembered @SpaselTogalk 's comment and thought that it must be firewall. 
So entered Control Panel > Windows Defender Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules 
and saw [those two](http://prntscr.com/kp1rjh) is bound to Python36 folder which is mine Python37. 
 Clearly it has not been edited automatically after I uninstalled py3.6 and updated to py3.7. 
Anyway, I edited and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It can because of many problems. Maybe some remaining of python or mismatch code. Instead of losing time with finding the issue, just push your Django project to the git and try to install virtual environment and install python3.7 and Django whatever version you used in your project (most up to date one is 2.1).

> You can follow this tutorials:
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/install/
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEcWRk9w0t0&t=354s

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work when I use virtual enviroment too

Comment: try to uninstall django and python37 from computer path so, maybe eventhough you have swithced to env, it still uses updated 37 from your path

Comment: I can share the code, but there is no point. there is nothing wrong with the project. let me try uninstalling

Comment: try open new project and check virtual env.

Comment: I just uninstalled django, created new virtualenv, created blank project. it runs but again does not request anything.

Comment: and try reinstalling

Comment: I reinstalled python made new virtual environment, installed django, run server, again no request.

Comment: I fixed it, check the comments